# How to store android.graphic.Path objects?

Tags: android, path

I can save all path-points.But It has a low efficiency to convert the points to path then draw them on canvas when the points is too much.So I think that  store the paths directly.

Comment: yes indeed, you have to make a custom `Path` class (a class that extends `Path` class) that implements `Externalizable` interface for example

Comment: and if you want to do that an easy way than use `android/util/PathParser.java` for parsing path data

Comment: Thank you very much，I will try.